# How to use loop in Jquery.Append() method in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing MVC application.

I am trying to append the div, with following code.
I want to use for loop to bind the data of viewbag in Append Method. 
L

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="row-fluid" id="ProductList">
</div>
</body>
</html>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#lnkAddProduct').click(function () {

 $('#ProductList').append("<div  class='span12' style='margin-left:0px' ><div class='span2'>" +

:<div class='span1'style='margin-left:0px; width:90px;'><input type='text' id='Quantity_" + IDD + "' class='clsQuantity'  name='Quantities' style='width:50px; margin-left:30px;' onblur='CheckQuantity(" + IDD + ");' /></div>" +


 // Now the list will come from controller and I wan to display it using loop... above html data remains same.

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.LocationList)
{   
<div class="span1" style="margin-left:15px;width:60px; value:  @item.Name">
 </div>
}

 //Going to remove below the hard codded values....and want to generate from Loop above  

"<div class='span1'style='margin-left:10px; Width:60px;'id='Bandra_" + IDD + "'></div>" +
"<div class='span1'style='margin-left:10px; Width:60px;'id='Dadar_" + IDD + "'></div>" +
"<div class='span1'style='margin-left:0px; Width:60px;' id='Bhivandi_" + IDD + "'></div>" +
"<div class='span1'style='margin-left:10px; Width:40px;'  id='Juhu_" + IDD + "'></div>" +
"<hr></div>");

        </script>
```

How to do this ?

Comment: it is unclear what you want to do.. Are you getting some data for your controller and then looping over your data to generate some dynamic html to present that data

Comment: Yes ankur, the same...

Answer (score 0):

```
var ht = ''
    var obj = {
        "LocationName1": "5558",
        "LocationName2": "8777",
        "LocationName3": "8555",
        "LocationName4": "2333",
    };
    $.each(obj, function (i, v) {
        ht += "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:10px; Width:40px;'  id='"+i+"_"+v+"'></div>";
    });
    $('#ProductList').append(ht);
```

Comment: Appending only $('#ProductList').append(ht); It will add new controls to div,won't remove existing controls inside div.

Comment: please check updated question, I want to bind the data which is in Viewbag.